# Slide Down Hidden Div On Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to create a hidden div (a header) that slides down once the scroll readers a certain point. Very similar to [this site](http://site.top-secret.be/).

I trying to inspect it to see how they did it, but I can't figure it out. I am not sure if they use pure CSS transitions or script. Many .js and javascripts do the opposite and have a div slide up/hide, but that isn't want I want.

I know that I have to build out two headers, one visible and one hidden. I am lost as to how to make the hidden header visible when I scroll down to 200px for example.

The HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
</div><!-- end logo --!>
<header>
<nav class="mainnav" role="navigation">
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
</nav>

<ul class="socialhead">
<li>fb</li>
<li>fb</li>
<li>fb</li>
</ul>
</header>

</div><!-- end header home --!>

<div class="header_homehidden">

<div id="logo">
</div><!-- end logo --!>
<header>
<nav class="mainnav" role="navigation">
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
<a href="#">link</a>
</nav>

<ul class="socialhead">
<li>fb</li>
<li>fb</li>
<li>fb</li>
</ul>
</header>

</div><!-- end header homehidden --!>
```

The CSS:
    
    .header_homehidden {
    webkit-transform: translateY(-90px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-90px);
    transform: translateY(-90px);
    }

```
.header_home {
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
}


.header {
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
background: white;
padding-top: 20px;
z-index: 999;
color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus ultricies convallis. Vivamus ornare diam sit amet nisl condimentum egestas. In mi nisi, molestie vel libero nec, facilisis egestas nulla. Integer condimentum nibh vitae rutrum consectetur. Vestibulum luctus sodales risus a elementum. Suspendisse porta felis vel urna rutrum mollis. In eleifend pharetra scelerisque. Praesent pellentesque molestie eleifend. Nulla magna nibh, vehicula vitae consectetur sed, eleifend id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec leo id magna vulputate tristique. Fusce nec neque metus. Etiam euismod, mi ac sagittis ultrices, nisl arcu ullamcorper neque, nec blandit mauris lorem non tellus. Vivamus tincidunt orci sem, facilisis dapibus velit luctus vulputate. Fusce sed nibh velit. Nullam lacinia eget felis et interdum. Ut facilisis non turpis quis dapibus. Aliquam iaculis in magna in pulvinar. Maecenas tempor tristique augue ut elementum. Nullam commodo urna a faucibus vulputate. Nam sodales nulla ac nisl iaculis laoreet. Proin turpis justo, sagittis vitae arcu et, elementum scelerisque risus. Duis vitae nunc faucibus, adipiscing metus nec, malesuada felis. Morbi ut auctor sapien. Morbi pharetra laoreet urna nec mattis. Nullam facilisis venenatis nunc, ut adipiscing sapien accumsan quis. Sed pellentesque tincidunt sapien, in consequat libero convallis sit amet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque imperdiet sem orci, vel venenatis purus suscipit a. Ut facilisis nunc elit, quis rhoncus nunc egestas a. Ut vitae dictum massa. Curabitur nec posuere arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris non tortor in est commodo commodo nec eget purus. Mauris enim lorem, lacinia sollicitudin libero vel, consectetur congue diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra fringilla velit at volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus ultricies convallis. Vivamus ornare diam sit amet nisl condimentum egestas. In mi nisi, molestie vel libero nec, facilisis egestas nulla. Integer condimentum nibh vitae rutrum consectetur. Vestibulum luctus sodales risus a elementum. Suspendisse porta felis vel urna rutrum mollis. In eleifend pharetra scelerisque. Praesent pellentesque molestie eleifend. Nulla magna nibh, vehicula vitae consectetur sed, eleifend id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec leo id magna vulputate tristique. Fusce nec neque metus. Etiam euismod, mi ac sagittis ultrices, nisl arcu ullamcorper neque, nec blandit mauris lorem non tellus. Vivamus tincidunt orci sem, facilisis dapibus velit luctus vulputate. Fusce sed nibh velit. Nullam lacinia eget felis et interdum. Ut facilisis non turpis quis dapibus. Aliquam iaculis in magna in pulvinar. Maecenas tempor tristique augue ut elementum. Nullam commodo urna a faucibus vulputate. Nam sodales nulla ac nisl iaculis laoreet. Proin turpis justo, sagittis vitae arcu et, elementum scelerisque risus. Duis vitae nunc faucibus, adipiscing metus nec, malesuada felis. Morbi ut auctor sapien. Morbi pharetra laoreet urna nec mattis. Nullam facilisis venenatis nunc, ut adipiscing sapien accumsan quis. Sed pellentesque tincidunt sapien, in consequat libero convallis sit amet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque imperdiet sem orci, vel venenatis purus suscipit a. Ut facilisis nunc elit, quis rhoncus nunc egestas a. Ut vitae dictum massa. Curabitur nec posuere arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris non tortor in est commodo commodo nec eget purus. Mauris enim lorem, lacinia sollicitudin libero vel, consectetur congue diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra fringilla velit at volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus ultricies convallis. Vivamus ornare diam sit amet nisl condimentum egestas. In mi nisi, molestie vel libero nec, facilisis egestas nulla. Integer condimentum nibh vitae rutrum consectetur. Vestibulum luctus sodales risus a elementum. Suspendisse porta felis vel urna rutrum mollis. In eleifend pharetra scelerisque. Praesent pellentesque molestie eleifend. Nulla magna nibh, vehicula vitae consectetur sed, eleifend id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec leo id magna vulputate tristique. Fusce nec neque metus. Etiam euismod, mi ac sagittis ultrices, nisl arcu ullamcorper neque, nec blandit mauris lorem non tellus. Vivamus tincidunt orci sem, facilisis dapibus velit luctus vulputate. Fusce sed nibh velit. Nullam lacinia eget felis et interdum. Ut facilisis non turpis quis dapibus. Aliquam iaculis in magna in pulvinar. Maecenas tempor tristique augue ut elementum. Nullam commodo urna a faucibus vulputate. Nam sodales nulla ac nisl iaculis laoreet. Proin turpis justo, sagittis vitae arcu et, elementum scelerisque risus. Duis vitae nunc faucibus, adipiscing metus nec, malesuada felis. Morbi ut auctor sapien. Morbi pharetra laoreet urna nec mattis. Nullam facilisis venenatis nunc, ut adipiscing sapien accumsan quis. Sed pellentesque tincidunt sapien, in consequat libero convallis sit amet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque imperdiet sem orci, vel venenatis purus suscipit a. Ut facilisis nunc elit, quis rhoncus nunc egestas a. Ut vitae dictum massa. Curabitur nec posuere arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris non tortor in est commodo commodo nec eget purus. Mauris enim lorem, lacinia sollicitudin libero vel, consectetur congue diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra fringilla velit at volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rhoncus ultricies convallis. Vivamus ornare diam sit amet nisl condimentum egestas. In mi nisi, molestie vel libero nec, facilisis egestas nulla. Integer condimentum nibh vitae rutrum consectetur. Vestibulum luctus sodales risus a elementum. Suspendisse porta felis vel urna rutrum mollis. In eleifend pharetra scelerisque. Praesent pellentesque molestie eleifend. Nulla magna nibh, vehicula vitae consectetur sed, eleifend id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec leo id magna vulputate tristique. Fusce nec neque metus. Etiam euismod, mi ac sagittis ultrices, nisl arcu ullamcorper neque, nec blandit mauris lorem non tellus. Vivamus tincidunt orci sem, facilisis dapibus velit luctus vulputate. Fusce sed nibh velit. Nullam lacinia eget felis et interdum. Ut facilisis non turpis quis dapibus. Aliquam iaculis in magna in pulvinar. Maecenas tempor tristique augue ut elementum. Nullam commodo urna a faucibus vulputate. Nam sodales nulla ac nisl iaculis laoreet. Proin turpis justo, sagittis vitae arcu et, elementum scelerisque risus. Duis vitae nunc faucibus, adipiscing metus nec, malesuada felis. Morbi ut auctor sapien. Morbi pharetra laoreet urna nec mattis. Nullam facilisis venenatis nunc, ut adipiscing sapien accumsan quis. Sed pellentesque tincidunt sapien, in consequat libero convallis sit amet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque imperdiet sem orci, vel venenatis purus suscipit a. Ut facilisis nunc elit, quis rhoncus nunc egestas a. Ut vitae dictum massa. Curabitur nec posuere arcu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris non tortor in est commodo commodo nec eget purus. Mauris enim lorem, lacinia sollicitudin libero vel, consectetur congue diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In pharetra fringilla velit at volutpat.</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
.header {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $(".header").slideDown();
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $(".header").slideUp();
    }

});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mzz2J/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function() {
  var bar = $('#headerSlideContainer');
  var top = bar.css('top');
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        bar.stop().animate({'top' : '0px'}, 500);
      } else {
        bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 500);
      }
   });
});
```

[**Working Example**](http://return-true.com/examples/sliderheader.html)

Source: http://return-true.com/2010/04/scroll-activated-slide-down-header-with-jquery/